# braintree dropin extra height

Tags: javascript, iframe, braintree

I'm using braintree dropin UI:

```html
<div id="braintree-dropin"></div>
```

```js
var braintree_client_token = "{{ braintree_client_token }}";

function braintreeSetup() {
    // Here you tell Braintree to add the drop-in to your division above
    braintree.setup(braintree_client_token, "dropin", {
        container: "braintree-dropin"
        , onError: function (obj) {
            // Errors will be added to the html code
            $('[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
            $('.braintree-notifications').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">' + obj.message + '</p>');
        }
    });
}

braintreeSetup();
```

And dropin generated has a lot of unnecessary height:

[image]
how do I go about debugging this and what might cause such thing ? 
I've tested with both production and live enviroments and the same problem persists.

EDIT:

You can find and inspect here:
http://floarplans.com/order/

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. I was not able to replicate this issue with my JSv2 Drop-in integration as I am not seeing the trailing space. Please reach out to our [Support team](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) with additional details so we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: @JacqueD Thanks! Quick question: is there a chance that bootstrap layout or classes might affect the iframe's height ? I've been able to change the width but is it even possible that my code somehow affects the iframe without specifically targeting it ?

You can take a look if you wish here: http://floarplans.com/order/

Comment: @Marijus, its giving a authorization error on the order lnk

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3):

It's because your theme.css line 2480 has the following rule:

```css
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    border: none;
}
```

If you include following css at the end of your head tag.

```html
<head>
<!-- Lots of meta and link tags. -->
<style>
    iframe#braintree-dropin-frame {
        min-height: initial;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

This should reset it back to normal. Because in css, latest and more specific rule overrides the others.